# Access Umbraco 7 Content from UmbracoApiController

Tags: umbraco7, asp.net-apicontroller

I have some trouble accessing Umbraco 7 Content from a UmbracoApiController.

This is my ApiController, with sample data, and i want to get real data from the Umbraco Content. How can i access the Umbraco Content?
[image]

This is how my Content is structured.
[image]

The solution if further readers would like to know, with help from http://creativewebspecialist.co.uk/2013/07/16/why-i-think-your-doing-it-wrong-umbraco-alttemplate-data-views/comment-page-1/
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can access it using Umbracos Content Service.

```
Services.ContentService.GetById(nodeId);
```

You can access the media nodes in a similar way using the MediaService. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for the answer, i used "Umbraco.TypedContent(umbNodeId)", haven't tried with ContentService.

Comment: The ContentService hits the database, using the helpers as per the above comment will be much quicker and more efficient by using the cached data.